# question of sampling in a binary-binary RBM

Tags: sampling, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I've learned that the weights of the RBM defines the joint probability distribution of the visible units and hidden units. So I try a very simple matlab code to prove that. I try two methods to calculate the joint probability distribution:

1.
I take a random 8X4 matrix as the weight matrix W of a no-bias RBM and a random 4X1 vector V as the initial vector of visible units. Then calculate p(h|V)=sigmoid(W * V) and take bernoulli sampling with p(h|V) to get hidden state vector h, then calculate p(V|h)=sigmoid(h * W) and take bernoulli sampling with p(V|h) to update visible vector V, then update the h, then up date the V and so on. I update the V and h for 200000 times and I take the latter 100000 set of states (I think after 100000 update it can reach the equilibrium, but I'm not sure about that of H and get p(h) from the 100000 h vectors. Then I calculate the probability of (h1,V1) as p(V1,h1)=p(V1|h1)*p(h1), the probability of (h1,V1) is the largest in all set (h,V).

2.I also calculate the joint probability distribution of p(V1,h1) by the energy:  $$p(h_1,V_1) = \frac{{{e^{h_1WV_1}}}}{{\sum\limits_V {\sum\limits_h {{e^{hWV}}} } }}$$

But the p(V1,h1) calculated by the two method are quite different. Please tell me where is my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: the W I used in the two methods are the same matrix